# paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Why this react native StatusBar currentHeight is not working?

```
paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
```

Comment: statubar.currentheight is returning 0 ? or what. To solve this kind of things its better to use https://github.com/react-navigation/react-native-safe-area-view

Comment: I can't see the specific view context you are using paddingTop... can you try it with marginTop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is automatically imported api from "Expo-status-bar"
if we need to get the height of status bar, we need to import "StatusBar" from react-native.
so we need to comment auto imported one.
like this

//import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';

import React from 'react';
import {
StyleSheet,
SafeAreaView,
Platform,
StatusBar,
View
} from 'react-native';

Answer (score 0):

Create a new js file like as below.

```
import { Dimensions, Platform, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

const X_WIDTH = 375;
const X_HEIGHT = 812;

const XSMAX_WIDTH = 414;
const XSMAX_HEIGHT = 896;

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

export const isIPhoneX = () => Platform.OS === 'ios' && !Platform.isPad && !Platform.isTVOS
    ? width === X_WIDTH && height === X_HEIGHT || width === XSMAX_WIDTH && height === XSMAX_HEIGHT
    : false;

export const StatusBarHeight = Platform.select({
    ios: isIPhoneX() ? 44 : 20,
    android: StatusBar.currentHeight,
    default: 0
})
```

Usage :

```
import StatusBarHeight from './StatusBarHeight'

console.log(StatusBarHeight)
```

Answer (score -1):

[React Native Device Info](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info) contains a list of useful functions (specially with respect to device height, width, etc) that can be used.

Try to use one of these functions and see.